# Deny user to see any database through DB_NAME()

Tags: sql-server, security, metadata

I've already prevented user to see any database (deny view any database to [login]) and it works.

But how to prevent user to list any other database using `DB_NAME()`?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Answer (score 4):

`DB_NAME` does not work as advertised before SQL Server 2016 (where the behaviour of `DB_ID` is also changed). For details, see:

[Information disclosure with the db_name and db_id function](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/755720/information-disclosure-with-the-db-name-and-db-id-function) (Connect bug report)

There is a [similar situation](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1090900/information-disclouser-with-a-number-of-metadata-functions) with other metadata functions, including:

- `suser_name`
- `suser_sname`
- `suser_sid`
- `user_id`
- `database_principal_id`
- `is_rolemember`
- `is_srvrolemember`

These issues remain unresolved (either by design, or by being 'fixed') as of the time this answer was written, as far as I know.