# Can see other user's databases in shared hosting

Tags: sql-server, security

This looks like a security concern but I do not know enough about SQL Server to know.

Using a shared hosting service, if I go to restore a database I'm able to see other user's databases.

I'm not able to restore their database to mine so I cannot see any of their data, just their database names.

Is this a security concern?

[image]

Comment: Depending on what version of SQL Server they are running it might be trivial for someone to get these names anyway by [just trying various integers with the `DBNAME` function](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136828/3690)

Answer (score 4):

I'd talk to your hosting provider's technical support people about this and get them to explain to you the security configuration they have on the `msdb` database, which is where those details are stored.

By itself, the list of database names likely does not indicate a security risk.  I'd ensure I wasn't giving away any details in *my* database names.

If I had SQL Server Agent Jobs running where the output was logged, I'd probably be somewhat concerned about others being able to see that output, so I'd confirm that (a) I don't have SQL Server Agent jobs with output, and (b) no one else can configure SQL Server Agent jobs to run against my databases.

Comment: This along with many other security concerns, eg if they allow trustworthy/CLR stuff or instant file initialization(for non zeroed space).